# codeigniter 2.2.6 session into database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session

I have problem with saving session intro database, codeigniter doesn't want to write session into database.

**My autoload.php**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session','database');
```

**My config.php**

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

**My table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: No. $config['cookie_prefix'] = "";
$config['cookie_domain'] = "";
$config['cookie_path']  = "/";
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE; I use Ubuntu 14

Comment: Just `False` the `$config['sess_match_useragent']`

Comment: It didn't help, I changed

Comment: FALSE `sess_expire_on_close, sess_encrypt_cookie, sess_match_ip`, just `sess_use_database` should be true

Comment: Again nothing, my database is still blank

Comment: in database.php, `$db['development']['db_debug'] = TRUE;` is it TRUE?? chk any error?

Comment: I can't found database.php, where should be?

Comment: $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;

Comment: `$config['sess_table_name']= 'ci_sessionsTest';` replace yur line with this, just for testing u will get the error in this condition..

Comment: Somehow works now :/

Comment: Any chance you use version 3.0? Seems this is starting point (session table) and you should realy consider about latest stable version.

Answer (score 1):

Just `False` the `$config['sess_match_useragent']`

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

**From the User Guide:**

`sess_match_useragent` is used to whether to match the User Agent when reading the session data.

**[CI Session User Guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)**

Comment: It didn't help, I changed.

Comment: you also need to FALSE `sess_expire_on_close, sess_encrypt_cookie, sess_match_ip` @Vlada

Comment: Again nothing, my database is still blank

Comment: Yes it does, and I don't know how :/